# How to prove NP-completeness of this mail-problem?

Tags: np-complete, np-hard, np, polynomial-time

Let's say we have **n** postmen that are bringing people mail in a neighbourhood, and that they start and end at the same post office. This situation can be decribed with a directed graph, where the vertices represent the people's houses the mails are brought to. If the graph has an edge from **a** to **b**, it means it is an accepted path to travel. Each postman must go from one house **a** to the next house **b** and cannot detour to a house **c** during that time. The post office manager says that a yes instance to this problem means that there exist **n** cycles so that

1. Each of the cycles contains a vertex **x** (represents the post office).
2. Every vertex except for **x** only appears once in each **n** cycle.
3. Each **n** cycle is of equal length.

**The manager then wonders how to prove that this problem containing 3 cycles (3 equals n, so there are 3 postmen in this case) is a NP-complete problem?**

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Steven I was thinking of reducing the Hamiltonian cycle problem since it also requires to start and end with the same vertex, but then I'm not sure how to deal with the 3 cycles in the reduction and the part about every cycle being of the same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an instance of partition $X=\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}$ you can build the graph $G=(V,E)$ where $V=\{0, 1, \dots, n\}$ and, for any pair of indices $i$, $j$ with $0 \le i<j \le n$, there is an edge $(i,j) \in E$ of weight $x_i$. Additionally, $E$ contains all edges $(i,0)$ for $1 \le i \le n$ with weight $0$.

The deposit will be vertex $0$. If you are able to find two cycles $C_1$, $C_2$ of the same length then the sets $\{x_i : i \ge 1 \wedge i \in C_1\}$ and $\{x_i : i \ge 1 \wedge i \in C_2\}$ will be a partition of $X$.
Similarly, a partition of $X$ induces two cycles of the same length in $G$.

This shows that the problem is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard even with just $2$ postmen.
You can generalize this reduction to any number $k$ of cycles by adding $k-2$ additional vertices $y_1, \dots, y_{k-2}$ along with all edges $(0, y_i)$ of weight $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ and $(y_i, 0)$ of weight $0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, why does it have to be k - 2 cycles and the weight divided by 2?

Comment: In the case of $2$ cycles, the weight of each cycle is the weight of a set in a solution of the partition instance, i.e., it is $\frac{1}{2} \sum_i x_i$. If you want to find $k$ cycles, you can modify the reduction to add $k-2$ "trivial" cycles. Since the weight of each cycle must be the same, you want the additional $k-2$ cycles to also have weight $\frac{1}{2} \sum_i x_i$. These cycles are of the form $0 \to y_i \to 0$.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: So if I got it right - if it is 3 cycles instead, we should add k - 3 "trivial" cycles or is it k - 2 always?

Comment: If you want to find $k=3$ cycles, you need to add $k-2=1$ extra vertices.

Comment: Okay, got it! Thanks for your replies.

Comment: However, when thinking more about this I realize that I'm not sure whether the instance of the partition X you suggested is of the vertices in a hamiltonian cycle or is it a reduction from another NP-hard problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question. Partition [is a NP-Hard problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). I'm reducing Partition to your problem.

Comment: Oh, my bad - I haven't heard of that NP-hard problem before. But cannot my problem be solved by reducing a Hamiltonian cycle (because of the same premise of every cycle starting and ending with the same node) or The traveling salesman problem which I read upon and find similarities with?

Comment: Yes, it can. Let $G = (V,E)$ be an unweighted graph and consider its weighted version $H$ in which each edge weighs $0$. Pick an arbitrary vertex $x \in V$ and designate it as a deposit. There exists a feasible solution to your problem with $k=1$ if and only if there is a Hamiltonian cycle in $G$. To handle $k \ge 1$ you can use the same technique as before (i.e., add additional vertices $y_i$ and the edges $(x, y_i)$, $(y_i, x)$ of weight $0$).

Comment: Great! Appreciate it!

Comment: Hmm, but should it still be k - 2 vertices that are being added if it's a reduction from a Hamiltonian cycle or how do I make sure each cycle turn out to be of equal length with the other cycles or is it the weight of 0 that makes sure that happens?

Comment: All edge weights are $0$, so the length of any cycle is $0$ and that constraint is always trivially satisfied.

Comment: Aha, alright! But you said I should add vertices if there are k>=1 cycles, should the amount of added vertices equal 2 if there are two cycles and 3 if there are 3 and so on?

Comment: Or is it still k-2 =1 extra vertice? Or was the 2 before because of the partition into two sets?

Comment: $G$ gives you a cycle. For each additional cycle you need and extra vertex (and the corresponding two edges).

Comment: Thank you for your clarification!